# how to select a drop down value of angular js application using selenium(java) using text

Tags: angularjs, selenium

[Please see the html source of drop down](https://i.stack.imgur.com/29r6N.png)
Below is myfunction to select a value from dropdown of angular js application

```
public String dropdownwithstringselect(String locatorName1,String locatorName2,String strtext)
    {
      try
      {
        wait(2);
        waitForElement(locatorName1);
        String locatorValueFromXML1 = utils.getLocatorData(locatorName1);                 
        WebElement sourceElement = driver.findElement(getElement(locatorValueFromXML1));
        sourceElement.click();
        String locatorValueFromXML2 = utils.getLocatorData(locatorName2);                 
        WebElement sourceElement1 = driver.findElement(getElement(locatorValueFromXML2));
        sourceElement1.getAttribute(strtext);

        extentTest.get().pass("Attribute value fetched from " + locatorName1);


      }
      catch (Exception e)
      {          
        extentTest.get().fail("Element - " + locatorName1 + " was not found");
        takeScreenShot();

      }
      return strtext;
    }
```

Comment: What is your problem? What is your locatorValues? What are the errors? https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @AlexeyDolgopolov , actually, I am trying to select a drop-down value of angular js application, can you please look at the image that I had posted.From the drop-down, I want to select a value by sllectby text( i am not able to do that ,since it is an angular application),So how can i Achieve that.

Answer (score 0):

To select drop down use following,

```
driver.findElements(By.className("Your dropdown class - ui-dropdown-items-wrapper")).click;
```

If drop down is taking time,  retrieve above in web element for click event. After that You can retrieve label value with the following syntax: `//span[contains(text(), "Your key value - Weekly Review")]` You can manage Key value with dynamic variable also,

Comment: first of all thanks .@Ishita Shah
How can i retrieve label value ?
as you mentioned I have stored my stored my drop down value by classname and retrived that in web element and also written step for click

Comment: on that element.
Please see below the steps that  i followed
String locatorValueFromXML1 = utils.getLocatorData(locatorName1);
    WebElement sourceElement = driver.findElement(getElement(locatorValueFromXML1)); 
    sourceElement.click();
..........................................................................................................
i have stored my locator value in an xml as below

<locator name="Schedule_drpdwnclassname">
  <value>class://ui-dropdown ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-helper-clearfix ui-dropdown-open</value>
 </locator>

Comment: It was typo error in above answer, I have updated it.  Please have a glance it.

Comment: Why you try to use XML file ?

Comment: Even my doubt is : "I have stored the locator value in WebElement sourceElement "
so from this , sourceElement.click(); will perform the click of dropdown
But how can i retrieve the label value from this sourceElement,
Can you please show me whic option should i use.

Comment: Your label is stored in <span> class, So you have to retrieve it by this syntax : //span[contains(text(), "Your label value like- Weekly Review") whichever you wants to select

Comment: I am storing all of the locator values in xml and calling that locator value from there

Comment: no,since it is angular js application , itried multiple time,its not working yet

Comment: Describe the error which you are getting, after using above code

Comment: Ishita i was able to select the drop down value with the above code.
But my concern was since i am storing my locators to XML ,i wont be able to dynamically call any text from the test case level.

Comment: try without XML storing,

Comment: I tried and it works for single variable and if i want to parameterise the key value dynamik variable,how can i do that ,Since xpath values comes like below

WebElement sourceElement1=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(text(),strtext)]"));
    sourceElement1.click();

Comment: where strtext is the text value that i need to parametrise

Comment: Rate and accept the answer, So its useful for others as well.

Comment: What exactly you want to achieve as parameter, Define it in html.